# Autoscaling tooltip in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I need to put some custom HTML code on the map. I have already done it using the tooltip with the invisible marker:

```
var marker = new L.marker([-19, -119], {opacity : 0});
marker.bindTooltip('<div>Some Custom Html</div>', {permanent: true, className: "leaflet-custom-label", offset: [0, 0] });
marker.addTo(map);
```

However, the tooltip's size remains the same on zoom, so the tooltip becomes bigger relatively to the countries when I'm zooming out.

What I want to do, is to make the tooltip with the size that is relative to the zoom level. Something similar is done in this example - https://embed.plnkr.co/hU6ip8T58tvE7CHJwniR/
But this code does not work in the latest version of the leaflet (though there are no errors in the console), and, as far as I can see, it does not support HTML content instead of plain text.

Is that achievable?

Update:
I added screenshots to show how it works for now. On the first image, everything is ok. On the second image I zoomed out, but the labels' sizes stayed the same, so the map becomes the mess.
[image][image]

Comment: Can you work up an example so we can see what you are talking about?